# XeLaTeX and plolyglossia: Danish hyphenation

Tags: xetex, memoir, hyphenation, polyglossia

I can't figure out how to do this properly, and I'd hate to go through all my files and adding a zillion `\-`s. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish} % set language for polyglossia

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{cham-pag-ne}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
champagne 
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

And here's what it looks like (pardon the potato quality):

[image]

What is the proper way of doing this? I'd love to have a global file, but I need the basics sorted out first ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It hyphenates as you have it in luatex, but xetex, like classic tex, doesn't hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, so you need a 0pt width space. Also because of some polyglossia timing? I needed to do the hyphenation exception after begin document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish} % set language for polyglossia

\usepackage{hyphenat}


\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}
\hyphenation{cham-pag-ne}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
\hspace*{0pt}champagne 
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is better for sure, but I see that some of my rules are ignored. Can I remedy this somehow?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard example?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{danish} % set language for polyglossia
    \usepackage{hyphenat}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \begin{document}\hyphenation{cham-pag-ne hav-de}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage*{0pt}age}{.5cm}
\hspace*{0pt}champagne champagne havde havde
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}`

   
Edit: Tried to make a code block, but seems it is impossible!

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard that's too narrow even for your extra breakpoints I added an image above

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard danish seems to have `\righthyphenmin=3` so it will not break just 2 characters at the end. Add `\righthyphenmin=2` just before the `\hyphenation`

Comment: Sorry, this is hard to reproduce without the full document. I don't see a new image?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard at the end of my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, David. I wish TeX was better at this stuff.